# VTCompressionSessionCreate works on iOS 9 but not on iOS 8

Tags: ios, video-toolbox

These simple lines of code (nothing else whatsoever in the app) work fine on iOS 9 (iPhone 6 and iPhone 4S), but not on iOS 8 (iPhone 5 and iPod Touch 5G):

```
VTCompressionSessionRef videoEncoder;
OSStatus err = VTCompressionSessionCreate(NULL, 1920, 1080,
                                          kCMVideoCodecType_H264, 
                                          NULL, 
                                          NULL, 
                                          NULL, 
                                          NULL, 
                                          (__bridge void*)self, &videoEncoder);
if (err != noErr) {
    NSLog(@"Error when creating compression session : %d", (int)err);
} else {
    NSLog(@"All systems go!");
}
```

I have also tried with lower resolutions, tried providing some or all of the optional parameters, in all cases it works on iOS 9 and fails on iOS 8 with the error -12902 (kVTParameterErr). Nice to know that some parameter is wrong, but which one and why isn't it considered wrong on iOS 9?

Note that VTCopyVideoEncoderList does give me a list where the avc1 (H264) encoder is present in all cases also.

Any idea what's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is a bit late but I guess it could be useful for others. For `iOS 8` you should specify `VTCompressionOutputCallback outputCallback` while creating a compression session. From the documentation:

```
@param  outputCallback
    The callback to be called with compressed frames.
    This function may be called asynchronously, on a different thread from the one that calls VTCompressionSessionEncodeFrame.
    Pass NULL if and only if you will be calling VTCompressionSessionEncodeFrameWithOutputHandler for encoding frames.
```

In turn, `VTCompressionSessionEncodeFrameWithOutputHandler` is only availabel starting from `iOS 9`:

`__OSX_AVAILABLE_STARTING(__MAC_10_11, __IPHONE_9_0)`

Comment: Good point, thanks for mentioning it. I ended up opening a support request at Apple, who answered that my bit of code indeed does not work on iOS 8 and there is no work-around. They did not mention the use of the VTCompressionOutputCallback.

Comment: It's strange because there is the obvious documented workaround. I use `VTCompressionSessionCreate` with a C-based `VTCompressionOutputCallback` callback on `iOS 8` and it works great.